# sqlalchemy returning results like b'result' could be unicode issue?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I belive it's something very simple, but on Python 3, actually i dont get why the results from this code are returning like b'something'

Actual code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData


def init():
    try:
        server = 'xx'
        db = 'xx'
        login = 'xx'
        passwd = 'xx'
        engine_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(login, passwd, server, db)
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False, encoding='utf-8')
        connection = engine.connect()
        metadata = MetaData()
        t_servers = Table('servers', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
        s = select([t_servers])
        result = connection.execute(s)
        for row in result:
            print(row['address'])
    except Exception:
        raise
    finally:
        connection.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

Query result:

```
b'localhost:7777'
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote the [python 3.3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an
>   instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only
>   contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater
>   must be expressed with escapes.

Comment: English ins't my strongest language... what that means?

Comment: The `b` prefix means your query result is returning an instance type of `bytes`, not `str`. You can read more about `bytes` [here](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#bytes).

Comment: Solved by converting my db table to utf8_bin